# SQL com duas informações diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho duas consultas no banco de dados que funcionam de forma independente, só que agora surgiu a necessidade de junta-las em um único `script`.

Fiz algumas tentativas, porém sem sucesso. Quem puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito.

**SELECT 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(codticket),
       usuario
  FROM vw_tkt_total
 INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
 WHERE anofechamento = '$ano'
   AND STATUS IN (3, 13) 
   AND ativo = '1'
 GROUP BY usuario DESC 
 ORDER BY COUNT(codticket) DESC
```

**SELECT 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(codticket),
       usuario
  FROM vw_tkt_total
 INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
 WHERE anoabertura = '$ano'
   AND STATUS IN (1, 2, 4) 
   AND ativo = '1'
 GROUP BY usuario DESC 
 ORDER BY COUNT(codticket) DESC
```

Muda a condição status de uma para outra alem de uma pegar ano de fechamento e outra ano de abertura.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta utilizar o UNION:

```
SELECT COUNT( codticket ) , usuario 
FROM vw_tkt_total
INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
WHERE anofechamento =  '$ano'
AND STATUS IN ( 3, 13 ) 
AND ativo =  '1'
GROUP BY usuario DESC 
UNION
SELECT COUNT( codticket ) , usuario
FROM vw_tkt_total
INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
WHERE anoabertura =  '$ano'
AND STATUS IN ( 1, 2, 4) 
AND ativo =  '1'
GROUP BY usuario DESC 
ORDER BY COUNT( codticket ) DESC
```

- Importante *

Utilize apenas 1 order by

Comment: Definitivamente a melhor resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode transferir as condições que estão no `WHERE` para um `CASE` dentro do `COUNT` e assim contar apenas os status que deseja para cada coluna:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN (3, 13) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS quantidade1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN status IN (1, 2, 4) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS quantidade2,
       usuario
  FROM vw_tkt_total
       INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
 WHERE anofechamento =  '$ano'
   AND ativo =  '1'
 GROUP BY usuario
 ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a forma totalmente correta, mas consegui resolver da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT x.usuario, SUM( pendente ) pendente, SUM( concluido ) concluido
FROM (

SELECT COUNT( codticket ) PENDENTE, usuario, 0 CONCLUIDO
FROM vw_tkt_total
INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
WHERE anoabertura =  '$ano'
AND STATUS IN ( 1, 2, 4 ) 
AND ativo =  '1'
GROUP BY usuario DESC 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 0 PENDENTE, USUARIO, COUNT( codticket ) CONCLUIDO
FROM vw_tkt_total
INNER JOIN usuarios ON codusuario = id
WHERE anofechamento =  '$ano'
AND STATUS IN ( 3, 13 ) 
AND ativo =  '1'
GROUP BY usuario DESC
)x
GROUP BY x.usuario
ORDER BY  `concluido` DESC
```